# How to add min and max validation for the custom WPF control?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, dependency-properties, blend

I would like to create a custom control with the multiple WPF dependency properties.

One of the properties is returning Thickness object.

Custom control should be suitable to be also used by designers in the Microsoft Blend.

Blend is allowing properties like Thickness to be limited.
For example BorderThickness cannot be less than 0.

How to create custom control with the thickness property where min value is 1 and max 3? I am expecting that also Blend will visually validate data in same way like BorderThickness for the Microsoft default controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define validation / coerce property callbacks when you register them. This [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745795.aspx) has a more detailed description of implementing dependency property validation.

In short though - you can specify validation and coercion callbacks for any property when you register it and check the thickness value inside of those callbacks.

For example, here is how the `Border`'s `BorderThickness` property is registered (code from ILSpy):

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty BorderThicknessProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "BorderThickness", 
        typeof(Thickness), 
        typeof(Border), 
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(Thickness), 
        FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender,
        new PropertyChangedCallback(Border.OnClearPenCache)),
        new ValidateValueCallback(Border.IsThicknessValid));
```

And here is the validation method itself:

```
private static bool IsThicknessValid(object value)
{
    return ((Thickness)value).IsValid(false, false, false, false);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to get min and max value? For example in case if i want to modify those values in numericUpDown editors and set max and min.

Comment: Well, just add two dep props for both min and max values and use those in your validation / coercion code.

Comment: I would add that in case you want to add those min/max values you should use the coerce callback (also discussed in the link in my answer) since the validate callback does not have any access to your control's instance. In coerce callback you get the control instance as a parameter (link to coercevaluecallback on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.coercevaluecallback.aspx )

Comment: Default borderthickness throws exception in case if we try to set invalid value -1,0,0,0 . So i was curios how to get min and max from this default property. And as I understand this is not possible.

Comment: Again, what prevents you to throw an exception in coerce callback method? And I do not get what do you mean by "how to get min and max from this default property". Dependency properties by themselves do not have a min and a max. You can implement them by defining two additional dependency properties (for min and max) on your control.

Comment: "what do you mean by" I am talking about default properties like "borderthickness" they are alredy defined in default type. and in some scenarios i have to get their possible min and max.

Comment: Dep. props do not have "min" and "max" boundaries. The existing `BorderThickness` also does not have any min/max value. It does not allow setting it to an invalid value (e.g. -1,0,0,0) because of the validation callback: `((Thickness)value).IsValid(false, false, false, false)` - this is why you cant set it to an invalid value. In detail - validation callback returns `false` in case thickness has an invalid value and because of that dependency property does not accept that value. The is NO min/max values on the `BorderThickness` property.